# derivation of algorithm complexity

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Refreshing up on algorithm complexity, I was looking at this example:

```
int x = 0;
     for ( int j = 1; j <= n; j++ )
        for ( int k = 1; k < 3*j; k++ )
             x = x + j;
```

I know this loops ends up being O(n^2).  I'm believing inner loop is executed 3*n times( 3(1+2+...n) ), and the outer loop executes n times. So, O(3n*n) = O(3n^2) = O(n^2).

However, the source I'm looking at expands the execution of the inner loop to: `3(1+2+3+...+n) = 3n^2/2 + 3n/2`.  Can anyone explain the `3n^2/2 + 3n/2` execution times?

Comment: Not saying you won't get a good answer here, but it might be better for http://cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: can you clarify what you're asking? Why `3n^2/2 + 3n/2` is O(n^2) or why it might execute that many times?

Comment: Sure. Why does it execute `3n^2/2 + 3n/2`?  I'm not understanding the division by 2.

Comment: `3(1+2+...n)` is not `3*n`, it's `3*n*(n+1)/2`

Comment: @GVIPProgrammer check out about Arithmetic progression

Comment: It exectues in `3n^2/2 + n/2` because k **strictly less than** 3j.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for each J you have to execute J * 3 iterations of internal loop, so you command `x=x+j` will be finally executed n * 3 * (1 + 2 + 3 ... + n) times, sum of [Arithmetic progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression) is n*(n+1)/2, so you command will be executed:

`3 * n * (n+1)/2 which is equals to (3*n^2)/2 + (3*n)/2`

but big O is not how much iterations will be, it is about assymptotic measure, so in expression 3*n*(n+1)/2 needs to remove consts (set them all to 0 or 1), so we have 1*n*(n+0)/1 = n^2

Small update about big O calculation for this case: to make big O from the 3n(n+1)/2, for big O you can imagine than N is infinity, so:

```
infinity + 1 = infinity
3*infinity = infinity
infinity/2 = infinity
infinity*infinity = infinity^2
```

so you after this you have N^2

Comment: Thanks!  I had totally forgotten about that property in relation to the summation.

Comment: @GVIPProgrammer its ok, I'm personally always check such formulas :) check update about amount of iterations and big O

Comment: One last quick question.  What about for single loops that are O(N).  Using n*(n+1)/2 as a basis, would it not equal n^2/2 + n/2?

Comment: @GVIPProgrammer what is single loop with n*(n+1)/2 basis?

Comment: A simple for loop: for(int j=0; j<n; j++){ x+= 5; }.  Is that not represented as a sum of integers j=1+2+...n = n*(n+1)/2?  But the complexity is O(n)

Comment: @GVIPProgrammer no, you have N iterations only, so for each J command x+1 will be executed 1 time, totally N times, so O(N)

Answer (score 1):

`Big O` notation gives an upper bound on the asymptotic running time of an algorithm. It does not take into account the lower order terms or the constant factors. Therefore O(10n<sup>2</sup>) and O(1000n<sup>2</sup> + 4n + 56) is still O(n<sup>2</sup>).

What you are doing is try to count the number the number of operations in your algorithm. However `Big O` does not say anything about the exact number of operations. It simply provides you an upper bound on the worst case running time that may occur with an unfavorable input.

Answer (score 1):

The sum of integers from 1 to m is m*(m+1)/2.   In the given problem, j goes from 1 to n, and k goes from 1 to 3*j.  So the inner loop on k is executed 3*(1+2+3+4+5+...+n) times, with each term in that series representing one value of j.  That gives 3n(n+1)/2.  If you expand that, you get 3n^2/2+3n/2.  The whole thing is still O(n^2), though.  You don't care if your execution time is going up both quadratically and linearly, since the linear gets swamped by the quadratic.

Answer (score 1):

The exact precision of your algorithm can be found using Sigma notation like this:

[image]

It's been empirically verified.